# Non value parameters in clone_from in gitpython

Tags: python, git, keyword-argument, gitpython

I'm trying to use the `clone_from` function from the `gitpytho`n library and I would like to pass the `git clone` parameter `--no-checkout` to the command.

According to the documentation, parameters must be passed as `**kwargs` and from what I understand, this must be a dictionary where the keys are the git parameter and the values corresponds to parameter values. My problem is that `--no-checkout` does not take any parameter values.

I have tried something like:

```
clone_kwargs = {'no-checkout'}
repo.clone_from(clone_url,local_repo_path,None,None,**clone_kwargs)''
```

and

```
clone_kwargs = {'no-checkout':''}
repo.clone_from(clone_url,local_repo_path,None,None,**clone_kwargs)
```

and

```
clone_kwargs = {'':'no-checkout'}
repo.clone_from(clone_url,local_repo_path,None,None,**clone_kwargs)
```

But all of these attempts fail. So, how do I best clone a repo without checking it out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This issue](https://github.com/gitpython-developers/GitPython/issues/589) in the gitpython project explains what you need to do:

```
Repo.clone_from(url, to, no_checkout=True)
```

So in your case it would be:

```
repo.clone_from(clone_url, local_repo_path, no_checkout=True)
```

Comment: Works great! Thanks a lot, @languitar !